# CanCan - Why does a can: create rule run when I'm not calling create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I have the following in my ability.rb file:

```
can :create, ThreadParticipation do |participation|
  Rails.logger.info 'XXXXXXX'
end
```

What's strange is that when I call ThreadParticipation.new, that rule is rulling and I'm seeing the logger output?

Why would can :create run when I'm just doing .new

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create is an alias for the actions new + create.
This has been to done to simulate C-R-U-D behaviour.
So,

```
:create = :new + :create
:read = :index + :show
:update = :edit + :update
:destroy = :destroy
```

Also,

```
:manage = :create + :read + :update + :destroy
```